# Posting separate lines from TextAreaFor into separate DB rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I get every line from TextAreaFor in Razor (or other form of HTML input) to be used by Create method (or how to modify that method) as separate value and inserted into separate row in DB.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Names name)
{
    unitofwork.Names.Insert(name);
    unitofwork.save();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.name)
```

**`Names` Model**

```
[Key]
public int NameID { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Opinion { get; set; }

[Required]
public int ID { get; set; }
public virtual NickName NickName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Names name)
{
    var names = name.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    foreach(var n in names) 
    {
        unitofwork.Names.Insert(n);
    }

    unitofwork.save();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: The issue is that n is of type String and Insert only accepts <T> as using dbSet.Add().

Comment: @CookieMonster I still don't understand where `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.name)` comes from. That suggests `model.name` is a string.

Comment: Yes that's a string but Insert uses dbSet.Add<T> so I need to pass an entity. That @Html.TextAreaFor will be a part of an object that will be passed to Insert function.

Comment: @CookieMonster What is `model` in `model.name` and how does that relate to the `Names` class?

Comment: Your answer was correct. The only issue was with creating an entity for dsSet.Add() from Insert method. I just needed to instantiate an object for each array value and pass it into unitofwork.names.Insert() method.